# How can I obtain info from this website using Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've written this code, and I can't obtain results. This is my first time I've tried this, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I run and only obtain info for teams in the top of the website, not other ones.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join

class FichaClub(Item):
    nombre = Field()
    email = Field()
    zona = Field()

class SacaClubes(CrawlSpider):
    name="Spider100"
    start_urls = ["http://www.ecuafutbol.org/web/asociaciones.php"]
    allowed_domains = ['ecuafutbol.org']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='asociacion_detalle.php*')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='club.php*'), callback= 'parse_items'),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = scrapy.loader.ItemLoader(FichaClub(), response)
        item.add_xpath('email','//a[starts-with(@href, "mail")]/text()')
        item.add_xpath('nombre','//*[@id="gallery-post-1511"]/article/div/div/div/p/strong[1]/text()')
        yield item.load_item()
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are trying to scrape the teams from the bottom table. To scrape this data you'll have to specify your parse_items to search for `<div class="table-responsive">`.

You could then iterate through the list and print out / do whatever you'd like with the team names. Here is an example of what I'd try using

```
 soccer = BeautifulSoup(start_urls, 'html.parser')
 table = soccer.findAll("div", class_="table-responsive")
 teams = []
for line in table:
       team_found = re.findall(r'([A-Z]\w+-*\w*)', line)
       teams = teams + team_found
```

Try this out. If it has issues, tinker with the line `table = soccer.findAll("div", class_="table-responsive")` and change the class name to other elements inside of that table. Make sure to use Chromes Inspect feature to pick apart the HTML.
Hope this was helpful!

Comment: hi, idea is enter on each association and then inside of each team to capture email info.

i think my code is correct, but is not giving email from club page.

Comment: In your problem definition, you stated that you weren't receiving the teams at the bottom of the website (table). My method would still work, just change the regular expression to something like : `^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}$` to find emails rather than team names.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand you.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: hello, sorry i dont know how can i put this inside my code